# Filter by Selected Cell's Value

Tags: excel, vba

There's a function called "Filter by Selected Cell's Value" on the excel right-click menu. How can I add this to the Quick Access Toolbar?
Also what is the VBA code for of the function of "Filter by Selected Cell's Value"? Many thanks
[image: excel right-click menu]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you click the Quick Access Took Bar and select "More Commands...", select the "Data Tab" and choose "Sort and Filter". I think that's the closest you can get to the exact command. None of this uses VBA of course, so if you're looking for a VBA solution, please respond to @FlexYourData and describe what you've tried so far.

Comment: This particular filter option is not under "Sort and Filter". I also have tried "Filter"/"Filters" in "All commands", but none of this is related. So far I can only find this filter option in the right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub FilterTableBasedOnActiveCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xCellValue As Variant
    Dim colIndex As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' Modify with your worksheet name
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")           ' Modify with your table name

        xCellValue = activeCell.Value
        Set xCell = activeCell

        If Not Intersect(xCell, tbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            colIndex = xCell.Column - tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1
            tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=colIndex, Criteria1:=xCellValue
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Hazel it would be great if you could explain what you are exactly trying to do that the code above does not cover that makes it limiting

Comment: I did try some VBA codes similar to yours, but there are quite some limits: 
1) if the data is a table and there some notes above the table (column headers are not on the 1st row), the marcro doesn't work;
2) it seems certain data cannot be filtered properly. for example: if the number has more than 10 digit after the decimal point, it shows nothing after running the macro.
The filter option "Filter by Selected Cell's value" from the right-click menu still works with above, which is the reason why I want to know if there is VBA code for this filter option.

Comment: @Hazel see updated code if it works on your end

Comment: I tried the codes and I got a run-time error '9': subscript out of range on the line "Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")"